# Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: mysql, linux

root@bilgimedya:/home/fevzi# tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log

2017-08-05T10:56:58.066946Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2017-08-05T10:57:27.459483Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requ                                                                                      ested 5000)

2017-08-05T10:57:27.459546Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (req                                                                                      uested 2000)

2017-08-05T10:57:27.625098Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is d                                                                                      eprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documen                                                                                      tation for more details).

2017-08-05T10:57:27.628050Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.0                                                                                      4.1) starting as process 2220 ...

2017-08-05T10:57:27.634811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available

2017-08-05T10:57:27.634870Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic b                                                                                     uiltins
2017-08-05T10:57:27.634882Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have enought space disk for your MySQL. Not only that, you need to make sure that you can connect to your MySQL instance, like:

```
mysql -u root -p<password>
```

For further reading on your issue about Zendesk, see:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213412829--HUB-ERROR-Zend-Db-Adapter-Exception-SQLSTATE-HY000-2002-No-such-file-or-directory